# how to extract the sub strings from given string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have fullname which should be divided into first name, last name and middle name.
Below are my example names.

```
1. WILLEMS, JAN MARIE J
2. HLAVACEK, PATRICIA K
3. KLIMEK, CHRISTOPHER
```

Now my first name, middle name and lastname should be

```
Firstname    Lastname    Middlename
JAN MARIE    WILLEMS       J
PATRICIA     HLAVACEK      K
CHRISTOPHER  KLIMEK
```

I tried with below queries.

```
            declare @FullName varchar(100)='KLIMEK, CHRISTOPHER'
Select  
    LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@FullName, 0, CHARINDEX(',', @FullName)))) As LastName
,SUBSTRING(@FullName,CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(@FullName)))+1,(LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FullName)))-CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(@FullName)))-CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FullName))))))
,SUBSTRING( @FullName , LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FullName))) -  CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FullName)))) + 2  , LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FullName))))
```

this does not give correct answer when it does not have Middle name.

Can you please provide your inputs?

Comment: What SQL engine and version please?
And then, do you expect multiple initials?

Comment: SQL 2012. Not multiple Initials. name can have or not have initials

Comment: Split on the comma, remove space from the front then split by space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting parts of names can get messy, but this might do what you need:

```
select 
    Firstname  = left(rest,len(rest)-charindex(' ',reverse(rest)))
  , Lastname
  , Middlename = case 
      when charindex(' ',rest)>0 
        then right(rest,charindex(' ',reverse(rest))-1)
      else ''
      end
from (
  select
      Lastname = left(name, charindex(',',name+',')-1)
    , rest     = ltrim(rtrim(stuff(name, 1,charindex(',',name+','),'')))
  from t
  ) as s
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UOMM64478

returns:

```
+-------------+----------+------------+
|  Firstname  | Lastname | Middlename |
+-------------+----------+------------+
| JAN MARIE   | WILLEMS  | J          |
| PATRICIA    | HLAVACEK | K          |
| CHRISTOPHER | KLIMEK   |            |
+-------------+----------+------------+
```

---

If the `middlename` should always be just a middle initial, with a length of 1, this would accomodate that:

```
select 
    Firstname  = case 
      when charindex(' ',reverse(rest))=2
        then left(rest,len(rest)-2)
      else rest
      end
  , Lastname
  , Middlename = case 
      when charindex(' ',reverse(rest))=2
        then right(rest,charindex(' ',reverse(rest))-1)
      else ''
      end
  , name
from (
  select
      Lastname = left(name, charindex(',',name+',')-1)
    , rest     = ltrim(rtrim(stuff(name, 1,charindex(',',name+','),'')))
    , name
  from t
  ) as s
```

returns:

```
+-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+
|  Firstname  | Lastname | Middlename |         name         |
+-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+
| JAN MARIE   | WILLEMS  | J          | WILLEMS, JAN MARIE J |
| PATRICIA    | HLAVACEK | K          | HLAVACEK, PATRICIA K |
| CHRISTOPHER | KLIMEK   |            | KLIMEK, CHRISTOPHER  |
| JAN MARIE   | WILLEMS  |            | WILLEMS, JAN MARIE   |
+-------------+----------+------------+----------------------+
```